# Display comment_form on separate page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I try to display "comment_form" on  node edit page, but can't get the rignt object, or arguments to pass to the form builder, here the code ->

```
print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('comment_form', $node));
```

this seems to work, but there are some errors, like missing argument

Comment: error was:

 Warning: Missing argument 3 for comment_form() in comment_form() (line 1841 of /var/www/example4/modules/comment/comment.module).

Comment: **!!! Here is solution ->**

`
    $comment = (object) array(
                        "nid" => **YOUR-NODE_WHERE-COMMENTS-GO**,
    
            );
    
            print drupal_render(drupal_get_form("comment_node_YOUR-CONTENT-TYPE_form", $comment));'

If you have truble, feel free to contact me

Comment: Clive has provided the solution here - http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21643/print-the-comment-form-with-php. This is for Drupal 7.

Comment: thanks for link, I try Clives solution, but form don't work well, becouse form on node add page, so u need to select in addition content type of node, where u place a comment

Answer (score 0):

It's easy and you don't need a specefic developpement, you can use the [Talk](http://drupal.org/project/talk) module or make a link for your page :

> /node/%/comments

or you can use a view

Comment: I was needed to display only "Add comment form", in the bottom of content submition form,  not all comments for a specific page,

and I try to use less additional module,

Answer (score 0):

For that use the panel module and panelize your page